# Where is the view menu?

Tags: views

When I want to see the wishlist of user 1, for example I go to `http://localhost/drupal/user/1/wishlist`. And I successfully get a well organized page.

But I don't see any items in the `hook_menu()` that describes this. How does it work?

Though there is `hook_views_api()`, I am not sure whether it is the place for view.

```
function commerce_wishlist_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['user/%user/wishlist/delete/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'commerce_wishlist_delete',
    'page arguments' => array(1, 4),
    'access callback' => 'commerce_wishlist_access',
    'access arguments' => array(1, 4),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  $items['admin/commerce/config/wishlist'] = array(
    'title' => 'Wishlist configuration',
    'description' => 'Configure wishlist',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('commerce_wishlist_admin_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer wishlists'),
    'file' => 'commerce_wishlist.admin.inc',
  );
  $items['wishlist-actions'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'commerce_wishlist_operations',
    'access arguments' => array('view own wishlist'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Comment: There is no user/%user/wishlist menu; that is why you cannot see it.

Comment: So is there any other possible to implement this menu? To the best of my knowledge I don't know how to do it.

Comment: The question is still not clear. Does `http://localhost/drupal/user/1/wishlist` return you a page?

Comment: Yes I can see the page. Now that I look into the codes, it seems hook_views_data and hook_views_api is rendering the view, though I don't how to use them yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some pages are generated entirely through views, bypassing the code. You can set the menu link and path in the view's settings. The navigation to that page would then be completely independent of the code.

If the page was created when you installed someone else's module, I would guess that the view is embedded into the site through code, and the path can be set that way as well. In that case, the path would be set in an array with something like this:

```
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'user/%/wishlist';
```

Contained in a function utilizing `hook_views_default_views`.

You can tell where the view is generated on the admin/structure/views page, where under each view title it tells you either: "In database", "In code", or "Database overriding code."
I'm assuming that the wishlist page is a view. So, if your page doesn't appear on the views admin page, then it's a different problem.

Comment: You are right! I find it in hook_views_default_views. Btw how can I create my own view? There are hundreds of entry in this huge array. If I want to reuse the views from others, besides $handler->display->display_options['path'], what should I also pay attention to?

Comment: I would just use the views gui. This can then be exported to code if you want using ctools

Comment: I got cut off in my last comment by accident: I would just use the views gui. Views that you've already created in drupal can be exported to module code using the ctools "bulk export" module, from which you can see how all the details are affected. You can look at existing views' code to figure out more of how to create your own. Does that help?